# CodeIgniter PHP 404 not found

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

He creado un registro PHP, para guardar los datos de un formulario HTML,  en una  base de datos. Al darle al botón guardar me sale "The page you requested was not found", no tengo la menor idea por qué.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {


public function index() 
{
    // Loading the model where the queries are executed
    $this->load->model('accounts');
    $this->load->library('javascript');



    $Cuentas = $this->accounts->getAllAccountInfo();

/*
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($cuentas);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
*/      
    $data =  array('Cuentas' => $Cuentas);
    $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);

}
public function demo()
{
    echo "Hola soy German";
}
}
```

//Modelo

```
<?php

class Accounts extends CI_Model {

    //$table_name = 'accounts'; // Main table name where the queries going to run

    public function __construct()
    {
            // Call the CI_Model constructor
            parent::__construct();


    }


    /**
     * This method returns the account information from all users on the database
     * @return Array()
     */
    public function getAllAccountInfo() {
        $query = $this->db->select('cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito')->get('accounts')->result_array();
        return $query;
    }

}
    ?>
```

Aquí están  el Controlador y el modelo.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cuentas por Cobrar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>" >
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>

      <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>


    <style type="text/css">
        #success_message{ display: none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="registro.php " method="POST"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Cuentas por Pagar</legend>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cuenta</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="Número de Cuenta" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombres</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="Fecha" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Banco</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Banco" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Monto</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="address" placeholder="Monto" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cuota</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="city" placeholder="Cuota" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Pago</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="Pago" class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Seleccionar Tipo de Pago</option>
      <option>Efectivo</option>
      <option>Tarjeta de Crédito</option>
      <option >Tarjeta de Débito</option>
      <option >Cheque</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Interés</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
  <input name="zip" placeholder="Interés" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<!-- radio checks -->

<!-- Text area -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Comentario</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Guardar<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-reverse">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cuenta</td>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
          <td>Monto</td>
          <td>Fecha</td>
                    <td>Pago</td>
                    <td>Banco</td>
          <td>Cuota</td>
          <td>Interés</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($Cuentas as $c): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $c['cuenta'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $c['nombre'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $c['monto'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['fecha'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $c['pago'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $c['banco'];?></td>
               <td><?php echo $c['cuota'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['interes'];?></td>


                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>

      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor pon tu nombre'
                    }
                }
            },
             last_name: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor pon tu apellido'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {

                    },
                    emailAddress: {

                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor ponga el nombre del banco'
                    },
                    phone: {


                    }
                }
            },
            address: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Inserte un Concepto'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your city'
                    }
                }
            },
            state: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ponga el valor de la cuota'
                    }
                }
            },
            zip: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ponga el valor del interés'
                    },
                    zipCode: {

                    }
                }
            },
            comment: {
                validators: {
                      stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        max: 200,
                        message:'Por favor ponga un comentario entre 10 y 200 caracteres'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {

                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca el código html que tienes, para ver como llamas el método del controlador en el botón.

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo he puesto en la publicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu form no estas llamando el método del controlador correctamente, estas llamando un archivo registro.php que no se sabe donde esta ubicado, además no tienes ningún método para guardar en la base de datos en tu controlador Home ni en tu Modelo Accounts, solo tienes un método para obtener los registros de la base de datos.

Si quieres guardar los datos del formulario puedes hacer algo asi:

**Controlador**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('Accounts');
  }

  public function guardarDatos()
  {
    //recoger datos del formulario
    /*Ejemplo para recoger datos del formulario. 
    Ya que estas enviando datos por post, para recojer los datos del mismo se hace de la siguiente manera.
    */

    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');  //donde el parametro que envias a la funcion post es el name del input en tu form. Y de la misma manera tienes que hacer con los inputs restantes.

    //llamar método del modelo para guardar datos
    $arreglo_datos = array('first_name'=>$firs_name);
    $this->accounts->saveData($arreglo_datos);
  }

}
```

**Modelo**

```
class Accounts extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            // Call the CI_Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function saveData($arreglo_de_datos_formulario)
    {
      if(!$this->db->insert("accounts",$arreglo_de_datos_formulario)){
       return $this->db->error();
      }

    }


}
```

Y en el action de tu form deberías poner la llamada al método del controlador de la siguiente manera

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url();?>/Home/guardarDatos" method="POST"  id="contact_form">
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial para que entiendas como funcionan los controladores y los modelos, ademas ahi existen ejemplos completos de como trabajar con los mismos.

[Documentacion oficial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, ahora sí está funcionando el botón. Disculpa la pregunta, pero pareciera que ya me estás haciendo el trabajo. Pero como hago en sí. Que los datos que he ingresado al form ya entren a la base de datos, porque eso es otra parte que no he de entender. Conozco la forma tradicional, más no la de CodeIgniter, por eso tanta confusión.

Comment: De nada, si te fue útil la respuesta márcala como solucion a tu problema, de esta manera otros usuarios pueden encontrarla util, y tambien ayuda a mejorar las estadisticas del sitio. Con respecto a tu duda, Ahora edito la respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo básico de como recojer los datos del formulario.

Comment: Hermano, en primer lugar gracias por dedicarme tu tiempo, te lo agradezco en el alma. Pero ha de suceder algo, aún del modo que me dijiste que entiendo que no está mal. Cuando le doy a guardar se va a otra página, pero no hace nada. Perdón por ser tan ignorante hermano.. y de nuevo gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Bueno no muestra nada por que no estas imprimiendo nada, prueba haciendo un echo despues de hacer la insercion en la base de datos, para probar que ingresó correctamente al metodo, realmente te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial de codeigniter, tienes que comprender los fundamentos del framework, ya que veo estas fallando en lo basico de codeigniter que son los controladores y modelos.